# ZF2 URL helper for subdomain

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, subdomain, development-environment

I have a website with four subdomains:

```
http://www.domain.com/
http://dev.www.domain.com/     # (dev environment for www.domain.com)
http://blog.domain.com/
http://dev.blog.domain.com/    # (dev environment for blog.domain.com)
```

I would like to add links from my `www` subdomain to my `blog` subdomain such that:

- If I am viewing `http://www.domain.com/`, then the link URL should be `http://blog.domain.com`
- If I am viewing `http://dev.www.domain.com/`, then the link URL should be `http://dev.blog.domain.com`

Is there an easy way to do this using Zend Framework 2's URL helper?

I have tried setting up my route for the `blog` subdomain as follows:

```
'blog' => [
    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname',
    'options' => '[:1st.]blog.domain.com',
    'constraints' => [
        '1st' => 'dev',
    ]
],
```

and the URL helper call from the view on the `dev.www` subdomain looks like this:

```
$this->url('blog', [], null, true);
```

I thought that passing `true` as the fourth argument would keep existing parameters intact. However, the URL being generated is always `http://blog.domain.com/` rather than the desired `http://dev.blog.domain.com/`

Any ideas? I wonder if I found a bug in ZF2. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The reason why the parameter did not remain intact is because it did not exist in the `www` subdomain. So, I needed to update my `www` subdomain routes as follows:

```
'www' => [
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname',
    'options' => [
        'route' => '[:dev.]www.worksessions.com',
        'constraints' => [
            'dev' => 'dev',
        ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => false,
    'child_routes' => [
        // Routes which were literal and part of www go here.
    ],
```

And now when using the URL view helper to navigate from `www` to `blog` or `dev.www` to `dev.blog`, the `dev` parameter remains intact! Voilà!